# org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: hibernate

We have arbitrarily received this hibernate error
**org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value** from production environment
but have not been able to generate this locally. I have given some pseudo code of our data structure and code to describe the relation.

```
class Parent {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
   @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
   private List<ChildA> childAs;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
   @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
   private List<ChildB> childBs;
}

class ChildB {

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_a_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private ChildA childA;
}
```

This error happens particularly in the Copy feature where the whole object graph is copied and persisted all at once cascading from the parent.

```
void copy(Parent source) {

  Parent copy = makeCopy(source);

  entityManager.persist(copy);
}

Parent makeCopy(Parent source) {

  Parent destination = new Parent();

  // Set other properties

  destination.getChildAs().addAll(
        source.getChildAs()
                .stream()
                .map(a -> {
                  ChildA childA = new ChildA();
                  childA.setProperty(a.getProperty()); // copy properties
                  return childA;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
  );

  destination.getChildBs().addAll(
        source.getChildBs()
                .stream()
                .map(b -> {
                   ChildB childB = new ChildB();
                   childB.setProperty(b.getProperty()); // copy properties
                   childB.setChildA( 
                             findCopiedChildARefByUniqueProperty(
                                     destination.getChildAs(), 
                                     b.getChildA().getUniqueProperty()
                             )
                   )

                   return childB;
               })
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
);

...

  return destination;

}
```

it has randomly caused **org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: ChildB.childA**  when running in production.

I have checked the hibernate query that it generates locally. For saving ChildB when copying hibernate seems to always first insert ChildB with null childA reference first, then inserts ChildA and after that updates childB with the childA reference and it works without any problem in local environments.

Production error Stack Trace:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: ChildB.childA
        at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:312)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
        at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:839)
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Note:

```
'hibernate-core' version: '3.6.10.Final'
```

Comment: Without seen  of `makeCopy` method I guess it's difficult to say something.

Comment: @SternK in makeCopy() we basically copy the whole object graph. I have updated the post with relevant code.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you set the mappedBy attribute of the OneToMany annotation? What does your other child class look like? Why do you not set the cascade attribute of the ManyToOne annotation in ChildB?

Comment: Did you have pre-persist validation checks disabled? It seems `findCopiedChildARefByUniqueProperty` is returning `null` for some `b.getChildA().getUniqueProperty()` in production